# Not able to view data in JSP file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch records from my database using Jpa repository and show it in a jsp file. But while running my application I am getting result as:

**Optional[com.app.daApp.model.Appointment@.......]**

Code of my controller, service and jsp file are as follows:-

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("getAppointment")
public String getAppointment(Model m)
{
    //System.out.println(myappservice.getId());
    m.addAttribute("result", myappservice.showAppointments());
    return "showappointment.jsp";
}
```

Service:

```
    public Optional<Appointment> showAppointments()
    {
        return apprepo.findById(this.id);
    }
```

Jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Appointments</title>
</head>
<body>
Your appointments:
${result}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of returning Optional<> return single data. Ex return apprepo.findById(this.id).get();

Answer (score 0):

try this, `.get()` at return.

```
public Optional<Appointment> showAppointments()
  {
    return apprepo.findById(this.id).get();
}
```